# Updated Software for Python APKs

Tags: android, python, android-studio, apk

For the past several days, I have been trying to get the following to work in regards to building an APK from a Python application: 1. Briefcase, 2. P4A, 3. Buildozer, 4. Chaquopy.

Yet with hardly any luck, I've only gotten as far on all of them to tell me I've installed Java incorrectly. I've tried installation in a variety of different ways and to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what to use to package my Python code into an APK? All the tools I've used so far are obsolete or have limited and varying documentation.

Answer (score -1):

The tools you list are the best ones currently available, and none of them are obsolete. If you need help using one of them, you should ask a question giving details of exactly what happened, either here on StackOverflow, or on the project's issue tracker.